# Conversion type error with native JPA query

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I wrote a native query to get the top 5 tags for questions, I created a class to hold the returned data - which is only the tag name and the total number of occurrences, but I get a type conversion error that I don't understand.

```
@Query(value = "select distinct t.naam as name, count(t.id) as total from vragen_tags vt " +
            "left join tags t on vt.tag_id = t.id " +
            "left join vragen v on vt.vraag_id = v.id " +
            "where v.actief = true " +
            "group by t.naam " +
            "order by total desc " +
            "limit ?1", nativeQuery = true)
    Set<TagAndCountResponse> getTopTags(int limit);
```

Class:

```
public class TagAndCountResponse {
    private String name;
    private int total;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    public void setTotal(int total) {
        this.total = total;
    }
}
```

But I get this error:

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap] to type [be.ambrassade.jeugdlink.model.response.TagAndCountResponse]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound(GenericConversionService.java:321) ~[spring-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:194) ~[spring-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:174) ~[spring-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
...
```

What is causing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer through another medium. (kudos to Les) The solution is to use projections (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections), so in my case rewriting the concrete class to this interface makes it work.

```
public interface TagAndCountResponse {
    String getName();
    int getTotal();
}
```